# STM32 USB OTG HOST Library hangs trying to create file with FatFs

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, usb-otg, fatfs

I am trying to create a file with FatFs on USB flash, but my `f_open` call trying to read boot sector for first time file system mount hangs on this function.

```
DRESULT disk_read (
                   BYTE drv,            /* Physical drive number (0) */
                   BYTE *buff,          /* Pointer to the data buffer to store read data */
                   DWORD sector,        /* Start sector number (LBA) */
                   BYTE count           /* Sector count (1..255) */
                     )
{
  BYTE status = USBH_MSC_OK;
  
  if (drv || !count) return RES_PARERR;
  if (Stat & STA_NOINIT) return RES_NOTRDY;
  
  
  if(HCD_IsDeviceConnected(&USB_OTG_Core))
  {  
    
    do
    {
      status = USBH_MSC_Read10(&USB_OTG_Core, buff,sector,512 * count);
      USBH_MSC_HandleBOTXfer(&USB_OTG_Core ,&USB_Host);
      
      if(!HCD_IsDeviceConnected(&USB_OTG_Core))
      { 
        return RES_ERROR;
      }      
    }
    while(status == USBH_MSC_BUSY ); // Loop which create hanging state
  }
  
  if(status == USBH_MSC_OK)
    return RES_OK;
  return RES_ERROR;
  
}
```

The main problem is the loop which creates hanging state

```
while(status == USBH_MSC_BUSY );
```

So I do not know what to do to avoid this. Using debugger I discover that state is caused by parameter `CmdStateMachine` of structure `USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam`, type `USBH_BOTXfer_TypeDef` is equal `CMD_UNINITIALIZED_STATE` which actually cause miss up of switch statement of `USBH_MSC_Read10` function.

```
/**
  * @brief  USBH_MSC_Read10 
  *         Issue the read command to the device. Once the response received, 
  *         it updates the status to upper layer
  * @param  dataBuffer : DataBuffer will contain the data to be read
  * @param  address : Address from which the data will be read
  * @param  nbOfbytes : NbOfbytes to be read
  * @retval Status
  */
uint8_t USBH_MSC_Read10(USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev,
                        uint8_t *dataBuffer,
                        uint32_t address,
                        uint32_t nbOfbytes)
{
  uint8_t index;
  static USBH_MSC_Status_TypeDef status = USBH_MSC_BUSY;
  uint16_t nbOfPages;
  status = USBH_MSC_BUSY;
  
  if(HCD_IsDeviceConnected(pdev))
  {
    switch(USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.CmdStateMachine)
    {
    case CMD_SEND_STATE:
      /*Prepare the CBW and relevant field*/
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWTransferLength = nbOfbytes;
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWFlags = USB_EP_DIR_IN;
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWLength = CBW_LENGTH;
      
      USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.pRxTxBuff = dataBuffer;
      
      for(index = CBW_CB_LENGTH; index != 0; index--)
      {
        USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[index] = 0x00;
      }
      
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[0]  = OPCODE_READ10; 
      
      /*logical block address*/
      
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[2]  = (((uint8_t*)&address)[3]);
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[3]  = (((uint8_t*)&address)[2]);
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[4]  = (((uint8_t*)&address)[1]);
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[5]  = (((uint8_t*)&address)[0]);
      
      /*USBH_MSC_PAGE_LENGTH = 512*/
      nbOfPages = nbOfbytes/ USBH_MSC_PAGE_LENGTH;  
      
      /*Tranfer length */
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[7]  = (((uint8_t *)&nbOfPages)[1]) ; 
      USBH_MSC_CBWData.field.CBWCB[8]  = (((uint8_t *)&nbOfPages)[0]) ; 
      
      
      USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.BOTState = USBH_MSC_SEND_CBW;
      /* Start the transfer, then let the state machine 
      manage the other transactions */
      USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.MSCState = USBH_MSC_BOT_USB_TRANSFERS;
      USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.BOTXferStatus = USBH_MSC_BUSY;
      USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.CmdStateMachine = CMD_WAIT_STATUS;
      
      status = USBH_MSC_BUSY;
      
      break;
      
    case CMD_WAIT_STATUS:
      
      if((USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.BOTXferStatus == USBH_MSC_OK) && \
        (HCD_IsDeviceConnected(pdev)))
      { 
        /* Commands successfully sent and Response Received  */       
        USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.CmdStateMachine = CMD_SEND_STATE;
        status = USBH_MSC_OK;      
      }
      else if (( USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.BOTXferStatus == USBH_MSC_FAIL ) && \
        (HCD_IsDeviceConnected(pdev)))
      {
        /* Failure Mode */
        USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.CmdStateMachine = CMD_SEND_STATE;
      }
      
      else if ( USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.BOTXferStatus == USBH_MSC_PHASE_ERROR )
      {
        /* Failure Mode */
        USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.CmdStateMachine = CMD_SEND_STATE;
        status = USBH_MSC_PHASE_ERROR;    
      }
      else
      {
        /* Wait for the Commands to get Completed */
        /* NO Change in state Machine */
      }
      break;
      
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
  return status;
}
```

Here is `USBH_BOTXfer_TypeDef` type declaration;

```
typedef struct _BOTXfer
{
uint8_t MSCState;
uint8_t MSCStateBkp;
uint8_t MSCStateCurrent;
uint8_t CmdStateMachine;
uint8_t BOTState;
uint8_t BOTStateBkp;
uint8_t* pRxTxBuff;
uint16_t DataLength;
uint8_t BOTXferErrorCount;
uint8_t BOTXferStatus;
} USBH_BOTXfer_TypeDef;
```

During the debug I discover that all fields of it is 0x00.

Here are my FatFs calls

```
int main(void)
{
    FATFS Fat;
    FIL file;
    FRESULT fr;
    
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;
    
    /* Enable SWO output */
    DBGMCU->CR = 0x00000020;
    
    GPIOD->MODER=0x55000000;
    GPIOD->OTYPER = 0x00000000;
    GPIOD->OSPEEDR = 0x00000001;
    
    while(1)
    {   
        if (!USB_MSC_IsInitialized())
        {
            USB_MSC_Initialize();
        }
        
        if (USB_MSC_IsConnected())
        {
            GPIOD->ODR = (1 << 15);
            
            disk_initialize(0);
            
            fr = f_mount(0, &Fat);
            
            if(fr == FR_OK)
            {           
                fr = f_open(&file,"0:DP_lab8.pdf",(FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE));
                
                if (fr == FR_OK)
                {
                    f_close(&file);
                }
                
                f_mount(0, NULL);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GPIOD->ODR = (1 << 14);
        }
        
        USB_MSC_Main();
    }
}
```

`USB_MSC_IsConnected` function is:

```
int USB_MSC_IsConnected(void)
{
    if (g_USB_MSC_HostStatus == USB_DEV_NOT_SUPPORTED)
    {
        USB_MSC_Uninitialize();
    }
    
    return !(g_USB_MSC_HostStatus == USB_DEV_DETACHED ||
        g_USB_MSC_HostStatus == USB_HOST_NO_INIT ||
      g_USB_MSC_HostStatus == USB_DEV_NOT_SUPPORTED);
}
```

And device states are:

```
typedef enum
{
    USB_HOST_NO_INIT = 0,  /* USB interface not initialized */
    USB_DEV_DETACHED,      /* no device connected */
    USB_SPEED_ERROR,       /* unsupported USB speed */
    USB_DEV_NOT_SUPPORTED, /* unsupported device */
    USB_DEV_WRITE_PROTECT, /* device is write protected */
    USB_OVER_CURRENT,      /* overcurrent detected */
    USB_DEV_CONNECTED      /* device connected and ready */
} USB_HostStatus;
```

The value of `g_USB_MSC_HostStatus` is received by standard USB HOST user callbacks.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. But that might be tl;dr. The ST libraries are notouriously bloatware. If that is **really** there it hangs, check where the flag is set and why it is not cleared. Likely an interrupt handler. Use breakpoints and a debugger.

Comment: I cannot see where do you call disk_read(). Can you provide the example of the code that is being executed?

Comment: @Ivan Angelov: Its HAL level function fatfs provide interface for it in disio.h, file than its manualy implemented with device driver usage in our case STM32F4 USB OTG HOST driver in file (usbh_msc_fatfs.c). FatFs call this function to perform read from physical device in my case FLASH DRIVE.

Comment: What version of the STM firmware are you running?  I have TM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.3.0 but I don't see the USBH_MSC_Read10(...) function, I have only USBH_MSC_Read(...)

Comment: @cleblanc: Here are some text from header file: `  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    usbh_msc_scsi.h
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @version V2.1.0
  * @date    19-March-2012
  * @brief   Header file for usbh_msc_scsi.c
  ******************************************************************************`

Comment: @cleblanc: So this function is declared in `usbh_msc_scsi.h ` and defined in `usbh_msc_scsi.c `.

Comment: You seem to have an old version.  You might try updating the ST firmware cube;
  * file    usbh_msc_scsi.h
  * author  MCD Application Team
  * version V3.1.0
  * date    19-June-2014

Comment: @hamboy75: No, it is 128 or 256 MB.

Comment: These days i have been including USB - host msc support to my card.. i didnt have any problem with usb-sticks, but i have the problems that you describe when using SD to USB adapters. I must say that i didnt try to create files. Btw update to version 2.2.0

Comment: http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries-expansions/stsw-stm32046.html

Comment: I though that there was a bug in the library, but it works fine aparently. The library with bugs is the usdb_msc_scsi, but the usbh_msc_scsi is working ok. You can see my post here: https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2fpublic%2fSTe2ecommunities%2fmcu%2fLists%2fcortex_mx_stm32%2fSTM32F2F4%20USB-MSC%204gb%20limitation&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug in ST host library. I've hunted it down, as my usb host was unable to pass enumeration stage. After a fix the stack is Ok.

There is `union _USB_Setup` in *usbh_def.h* file in "STM32Cube/Repository/STM32Cube_FW_F7_V1.13.0/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Host_Library/Core/Inc" (any chip, not only F7, any version, not only V1.13.0). It has uint16_t bmRequestType and uint16_t bRequest. These two fileds must be uint8_t as of USB specs. Fixing this issue made usb host go as needed. Enumeration stage passes ok, and all other stages as well.

Comment: All these fields has type `uint8_t` by default, but it does not work.

Comment: Ok, does your flash drive gets enumerated by the usb host? And then, does the device class gets started?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but currently I have not access to microcontroller now, so I'll give some reward to you.